# Winform: How to display form controls only when all controls have been loaded?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a windows form with several labels and buttons. 
Eg:

```
Name : ____
Age  : ____
Phone: ____

btnCancel |  btnModify
```

The values of the labels (____) are fetched from database on page load. 
When I open this form labels such as Name,Age,Phone get loaded first, then ____ get updated when query returns result, and then btnCancel and btnModify get displayed. I want entire form to load at once when the value have been fetched. It would also be great if I could give some kind of indication that system is processing.

Comment: I know this does not answer your question, and can even be considered off topic, but you really need to start using WPF. Once you get over that steep(and I mean REALLY steep) learning curve, there will simply be no way you can ever go back to WinForms.

Comment: @Krythic duly noted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put all of the controls into a "panel" and then set the Panel.Visible to false and when the load and update are complete set the Panel.Visible to true.

The easiest way to signal a busy state is to use Control.UseWaitCursor property. You should be doing the actual loading in another thread.

For example, inside a Form or a UserControl:

```
panel1.Visible = false;
this.UseWaitCursor = true;
Task.Run(() => { 
    var data = LoadTheData();
    this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        labelName.Text = data.Name;
        panel1.Visible = true;
        this.UseWaitCursor = false;
    }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for groupbox as well.  As for `UseWaitCursor` that wont help much because I am creating an application for KIOSK. There probably  wont be a cursor on the screen.
I have marked your answer but please do edit if you know any other way to signal busy state.

Comment: I think you can set the Image of a PictureBox control to an animated gif file... having your task running on a background thread is necessary for this to work.